# Reading Javascript FormData value in Asp.net Web api Httpresponsemessage

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I have a Web api which is decorated with **[HttpPost]** which is used to upload all information passed in parameter but getting this error

**Error**

[image]

**Controller**

```
  [HttpPost]
   public HttpResponseMessage questionnairesubmit(HttpRequestMessage form)
    {

     //want to get json of "questionlist" which is send from javascript like
      var QuestionnaireList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<outRightLogos.Areas.client.WebApiModel.AttributeValueTB>>(form["questionlist"]);


    }
```

Here is javascript sending Json model with name **questionlist** this I want to fetch in controller.I read FormData() from [Here](http://www.javascripture.com/FormData)

**Javascript**

```
var data = new FormData();
var QuestionnaireList = [];
 QuestionnaireList.push({

            FieldID: $(this).attr("data-fieldid"),
            attributeID: $(this).attr("data-attributeid"),
            attributeValue: $(this).val(),
            websitesID: 2,
            OrderID: $('#orderid').val(),
            orderbitID: $('#orderbidid').val(),
            serviceId: $(this).attr("data-serviceid"),
            subServiceId: $(this).attr("data-subserviceid"),
            IsSubmit: IsSubmit,
        });

data.append("questionlist", JSON.stringify(QuestionnaireList));
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: path,
                    contentType: 'application/json',//"application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    processData: false,
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: data,

                    success: function (result) {

                        if (result.sucess == "save") {
                            alert('Your form has been saved.');

                        }
                        else if (result.sucess == "Submit") {
                            alert('Your form has been submitted.');
                            window.location.href = result.Url;
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert('Oh no ');
                    }

                });
```

Here is a model class **AttributeValueTB**

**Class**

```
 public class AttributeValueTB
{
    public long attributeValueID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(200)]
    public string attributeValueCode { get; set; }

    public int FieldID { get; set; }

    public int attributeID { get; set; }

    public string attributeValue { get; set; }

    public int websitesID { get; set; }

    public long OrderID { get; set; }
    public long orderbitID { get; set; }
    public long serviceId { get; set; }
    public long subServiceId { get; set; }
    public string extra1 { get; set; }
    public string extra2 { get; set; }
    [StringLength(200)]
    public string attributeCode { get; set; }
    public bool isActive { get; set; }

    public bool isShow { get; set; }
    public bool IsSubmit { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTime? createDate { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTime? modifiedDate { get; set; }

    public int? createBy { get; set; }

    public int? modifiedBy { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "timestamp")]
    [MaxLength(8)]
    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] Timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to serialize anything manually, as long as you've provided a model class in C#.

[Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm) is quite smart and serializes your parameters automagically.

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage QuestionnaireSubmit(AttributeValueTB form)
{
   // Form is serialized and can be used here       

}
```

If you'd like to read the cookies too, you could use `Request.Cookies` in this method.

Answer (score 1):

you need to collect information from 'jsoncontent' not from 'form'

```
HttpContent requestContent = Request.Content;
string jsonContent = requestContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
entityclass obj= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<entityclass>(jsonContent);
```

and if you using class object as parameter also work with your context, need to change the method as put like this.

```
[HttpPut]
public HttpResponseMessage Put(int id)
{
  HttpContent requestContent = Request.Content;
  string jsonContent = requestContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
  entityclass obj= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<entityclass>(jsonContent);
  ...
}
```

Comment: what error you getting ? check in your jsoncontent your required content is there or not